# Trying to install using mix, (Mix) Could not access url error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to install elixir packages and whenever I use mix command, I get this kind of message,

```
mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/releases/download/v1.0.0/phoenix_new-1.0.0.ez
Are you sure you want to install archive https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/releases/download/v1.0.0/phoenix_new-1.0.0.ez? [Yn] y
** (Mix) Could not access url https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/releases/download/v1.0.0/phoenix_new-1.0.0.ez, error: {:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'github.com', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], :nxdomain}]}
```

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Looks like a DNS issue. `nxdomain` means "non existent domain". Can you access github.com via a web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to ensure than ~/.mix/archives directory has write permission.

`sudo chmod a+rw ~/.mix/archives/` solved the problem.